# ReSharper Code Cleanup Adds Redundant Qualifiers

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2017, resharper

When I apply ReSharper's Code Cleanup, it is added qualifiers to static methods. I then see a diagnostic IDE0002 telling me the name can be simplified.
This isn't a problem when I have *Code Editing > General Formatter Style > Enable StyleCop* support unchecked.

**Example**

```
public class Foo
{

    public void Bar()
    {
        StaticMethod();
    }

    private static void StaticMethod()
    {   
    }
}
```

Gets "cleaned up" to:

```
public class Foo
{
    public void Bar()
    {
        Foo.StaticMethod();
    }

    private static void StaticMethod()
    {

    }
}
```

How do I prevent ReSharper Code Cleanup from adding this qualifier and leaving the code unchanged?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Untick all checkboxes in `Members to qualify` dropdown list here `ReSharper | Options | Code Editing | C# | Code Style | Static members qualifications`

[image]

Since you've mentioned that unticking `Enable StyleCop support` checkbox in ReSharper Options helped, it looks like there is a setting in `settings.stylecop` file in your solution which overrides ReSharper setting (more about support for StyleCop config file you can find in `Enable StyleCop support` [here](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/resharper/2018.3/Reference__Options__General_Formatter_Style.html))

Comment: Static Member Qualification does not have any checkboxes in the Preference column. Just drop down lists. Reference Qualification, however, does have some checkboxes. I unchecked all of these but it made no difference, unfortunately.

Comment: I've added a screenshot to show what dropdown list I am talking about

Comment: The checkbox for methods is already unchecked. It's still adding the static qualifier.

Comment: Do you have `settings.stylecop` in your solution? Looks like the file has a setting which overrides ReSharper one according to https://www.jetbrains.com/help/resharper/2018.3/Reference__Options__General_Formatter_Style.html | Enable StyleCop support

Comment: Yep, you're right I do. Well spotted. Do you want to add this answer?

Comment: Updated the answer